# How to obtain more information from Ajax call to PHP file failure?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, error-handling, internal

I moved my website on a server in order to go live, but I am getting an issue with an Ajax call to a PHP file designed to return a text value. I am trying to find what the bug is. The code works on my local PC.

The error I get from the Ajax call is:

```
Error: error Internal Server Error
```

I am using the following piece of code to perform the call:

```
function goClick(ttype, vvalue) {

    $.get(fw_script, { type: ttype, value: vvalue, langpref: langpref })
        .success(function(result) {
            setResult(result);
        })
        .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            setResult("Error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
            alert("Failure");
        });

}
```

How can I obtain more information about what could cause this issue? I am not an expert at PHP. Is there some equivalent of Java's `try {} catch {} finally{}` in PHP? Would this be the proper way to catch exceptional errors on the server side? Should I wrap my PHP code with a catch? How to retrieve information about internal errors?

Comment: ensure that the requests is reaching the desired php file first. What do you see in firebug ? (install firebug firefox plugin ) to get error details

Comment: Called URL seems correct according to FireBug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exactly right. `try {} catch {}` works the same way in PHP.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Internal Server Errors are often caused by a typo or similar in the PHP file. You can try to enable error logging to get more details about the error.

Answer (score 2):

Put following code on top of php script
 // log php errors

```
<?php
@ini_set('log_errors','On'); // enable or disable php error logging (use 'On' or 'Off')
@ini_set('display_errors','Off'); // enable or disable public display of errors (use 'On' or 'Off')
@ini_set('error_log','/home/path/logs/php-errors.log'); // path to server-writable log file
?>
```